# How to find the maximum and minimum of integers without using a list or infinity?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is for an assignment where we're supposed to write code that asks a user for a number of integers, they input that number, then it asks them to, one at a time, put those numbers in. It then is supposed to find the maximum and minimum of those numbers and give them back to the user. We're at a point in the program where we can't use infinity or lists as well. I managed to do the first half, but I can't understand how to separate the numbers to compare them and find the values. I know what's not working now has something to do with the loop, but I'm not sure where to go. I'm a beginner, so literally any help is appreciated.

Also for clarification, we're using Python.

```
int_num = int(input("How many integers would you like to enter? "))
total = 0

print("Please enter", int_num, "integers.")

for num in range(1, int_num + 1):
    integers = int(input())
    if integers < min:
        min_value = min
    elif integers > max:
        max_value = max


print("min:", min_value)

print("max:", max_value)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code in your question? There are a number of basic syntax errors there that need to be cleaned up before we can assess the logic you're trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So another way is that you can assume the first inserted number is your minimum/maximum value. Then iterate through the rest(n-1) integers:

```py
int_num = int(input("How many integers would you like to enter? "))
print("Please enter", int_num, "integers.")

min_value = max_value = int(input())

for _ in range(int_num - 1):
    n = int(input())
    if n < min_value:
        min_value = n
    elif n > max_value:
        max_value = n


print("min:", min_value)
print("max:", max_value)
```

**Note-1**: Don't use the built-in names as your variable name. (`min` and `max`)

**Note-2**: There is no point for having `range(1, int_num + 1)` Because you don't even use the loop variable.

**Note-3**: You're not gonna calculate the `total` of the numbers, so delete that extra variable.